# Excel: Copying values,

Tags: excel

Noob question: I have some cells containing formulas calculating me values based on the values of other cells in the same row.

I would like to copy the number value of the formula cells, yet when I copy them, it only copies the formula, leaving me with nothing but 0s in my pasted document.

Thanks a lot already for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Use paste special -> values

a quick keyboard way to get there is

press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> then press <kbd>e</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> Let go of <kbd>alt</kbd> then enter

seems long but when you get used to it its quick

There is also <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> from Jerry in the comments below

Comment: It's even faster on Excel 2003/07/10 with Alt+H+V+V

Comment: Added it - Never know about that

Answer (score 1):

Use [Paste Special](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-paste-special-to-insert-static-or-linked-data-into-excel-HP001108276.aspx) -> Values to copy values only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Paste Special to paste only the values from a cell in the following way:

1. Copy the cell whose values you want to use
2. Right-click the place you want to copy to
3. Go to Paste Special and click Paste Values

This pastes only the values of the cell and not the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Choose Edit menu, and "Copy to Scrapbook". That will copy the value instead.

Answer (score 0):

simply pasting the copied data will copy the formulas with changed reference, resulting in zeros or some unexpected results. To avoid this use "value" from "Paste Special" menu.